# Pig Query - Giving inconsistent results in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-emr

I am new to PIG. I have written one query which is not working as expected. I am trying to process Google ngrams dataset provided to me.

1. I load the data which is 1GB

   ```
   bigrams = LOAD '$(INPUT)' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, occurrences:int, books:int);
   ```
2. Then I select a subset which is limited to 2000 entries

   ```
   limbigrams = LIMIT bigrams 2000;
   ```
3. Then see the dump of the limited data (pasting sample output)

   ```
   (GB product,2006,1,1)
   (GB product,2007,5,5)
   (GB wall_NOUN,2007,27,7)
   (GB wall_NOUN,2008,35,6)
   (GB2 ,_.,1906,1,1)
   (GB2 ,_.,1938,1,1)
   ```
4. Now I do a group by on limbigrams

   ```
   D = GROUP limbigrams BY bigram;
   ```
5. When I see the data dump of D I see an entirely different data set (sample)

   > (GLABRIO *.*,1977,3,3),(GLABRIO *.*,1992,3,3),(GLABRIO *.*,1997,1,1),(GLABRIO *.*,2000,6,6),(GLABRIO *.*,2001,9,1),(GLABRIO *.*,2002,24,3),(GLABRIO *.*,2003,3,1)})
   >   (GLASS FILMS,{(GLASS FILMS,1978,1,1),(GLASS FILMS,1976,2,1),(GLASS FILMS,1970,3,3),(GLASS FILMS,1966,7,1),(GLASS FILMS,1962,1,1),(GLASS FILMS,1958,1,1),(GLASS FILMS,1955,1,1),(GLASS FILMS,1899,2,2),(GLASS FILMS,1986,6,3),(GLASS FILMS,1984,1,1),(GLASS FILMS,1980,7,3)})

Now I am not attaching the entire output because there is not even a single row of overlap between both the outputs (i.e. before group-by and after group-by). Hence it really doesn't matter to see the output files.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The dumps are accurate. The `GROUP BY` operator in Pig creates a single record for each group and puts every record belonging to that group inside a bag. You can indeed see this in the last record of your second dump. The record stands for the group GLASS FILMS and has a bag containing records which have the bigram as GLASS FILMS. You can read more about the `GROUP BY` operator here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_group_operator.htm

Comment: Hi. I will check the link. But my question in general was when I run the query over the entire set of data I do not get inconsistent results. But when I limit the data and then apply operations on the filtered dataset then I get results which are in no way limited to that dataset that was limited in the previous step.